# How to play an audio of a given string on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, nsstring

how to play the audio for a given string. If I enter a text and press play button to express the audio of given string. Is there any solution. Please suggest a solution.

Thnaky you,
Madan mohan

Comment: How to implement this task with out using third party tools and others

Comment: What you're asking is how to create your own TTS engine - I'm afraid you're not going to get an answer to that on here as it's an extremely complicated question. Why not make use of the iPhone TTS library I posted (under MIT license), or the CMU Flist speech synthesizer posted by hotpaw2 - they are both viable solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps check out the iPhone TTS library at http://bitbucket.org/sfoster/iphone-tts/ - it seems to include a demo project, and looks to be pretty straight-forward to drop into a project and use.

Comment: Nice. But, Can we use this code for implementation or any claims

Answer (score 0):

The [CMU Flite speech synthesizer](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/flite/) has been ported to the iPhone.  There is a license on their site which you can read yourself.